Broken LZW Compression Algorithm in Node.js
I've really been struggling the past few days with my final project for class.
I'm trying to implement the LZW Compression Algorithm in Node.js (v20)—specifically to work with a variety (images, plain text, etc) of binary (this is more important to me) and text files, which can each be up to 10MB in size.
Below is the following code I've written (albeit with some help), and I would really appreciate it if someone could aid me in figuring out what I'm missing. As it currently stands, really small text files (like one to two sentences) work, but anything beyond that gives a different, decompressed output than the source input.
// Filename: logic/index.ts

import { Readable, Writable } from 'node:stream';

const INITIAL_TABLE_SIZE = 128;

export async function compress(readable: Readable): Promise<Buffer> {
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {

        const table = new Map<string, number>();
        let index = 0;

        
        while (index < INITIAL_TABLE_SIZE) {
            table.set(String.fromCharCode(index), index);
            index++;
        }

        const output: number[] = [];
        let phrase = '';

        const writeable = new Writable({
            write: (chunk: Buffer, _encoding, callback) => {
                for(let i = 0; i < chunk.length; i++) {
                    const char = String.fromCharCode(chunk[i]!);

                    const key = phrase + char;

                    if(table.has(key)) {
                        phrase = key;
                    } else {
                        output.push(table.get(phrase)!);
                        table.set(key, index++);
                        phrase = char;
                    }
                }
                callback()
            },
            final: (callback) => {
                if (phrase !== '') {
                    output.push(table.get(phrase)!);
                }

                resolve(Buffer.from(output));
                callback()
            }
        })

        readable.pipe(writeable);

    })
}

export async function decompress(readable: Readable): Promise<Buffer> {

    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {

        const table = new Map<number, string>();
        let index = 0;

        
        while (index < INITIAL_TABLE_SIZE) {
            table.set(index, String.fromCharCode(index));
            index++;
        }

        let output = '';
        
        const writable = new Writable({
            write: (chunk: Buffer, _encoding, callback) => {
                let phrase = String.fromCharCode(chunk[0]!)
                output = phrase;
                let value = '';

                for(let i = 1; i < chunk.length; i++) {
                    const number = chunk[i]!;

                    if (table.get(number) !== undefined) {
                        value = table.get(number)!;
                    } else if (number === index) {
                        value = phrase + phrase[0];
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('Error in processing!')
                    }

                    output += value;

                    table.set(index++, phrase + value[0]);
        
                    phrase = value;
                }

                callback()
            },
            final: (callback) => {
                resolve(Buffer.from(output))
                callback()
            }
        })
        

        readable.pipe(writable);

    })

}

// Filename: index.ts

import { createReadStream } from 'node:fs';
import { readFile, writeFile } from 'node:fs/promises';
import { compress, decompress } from './logic/index.js';

const source = await readFile('./data/sample.txt');
console.log('Source:       ', source)
writeFile('./data/input', source);

const input = createReadStream('./data/input')
input.on('data',  (chunk) => console.log('Input:        ', chunk));

const compressed = await compress(input);
console.log('Compressed:   ', compressed);
writeFile('./data/zip', compressed);

const zip = createReadStream('./data/zip')
zip.on('data', (chunk) => console.log('Zip:          ', chunk))

const decompressed = await decompress(zip);
console.log('Decompresssed:', decompressed)
writeFile('./data/output', decompressed)

console.log('Passes:', decompressed.equals(source))

In advance, thank you so much for your time—I really appreciate it!
